# Imagebutton not display image

Tags: c#, asp.net

once i click button, my image1 will display an image;

when i set my imagePath to

```
Server.MapPath("~/SME IMAGE/anonymous_avatar.gif");
```

my url not work

but when i set my path to

```
"~/SME IMAGE/anonymous_avatar.gif"
```

my url work

so basically what happen to my Server.MapPath?

```
    try
    {

        string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/SME IMAGE/anonymous_avatar.gif");
        Image1.ImageUrl = imagePath;
        Response.Write("success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two URL's in the rendered page (in the browser)?

Comment: @Niklas , i think they are no different, is that any way to check the differential ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server.MapPath` it translates the "web" path into your local path. 

So `Server.MapPath("Server.MapPath")` it will give the local location of your file. 

You are assigning this to the `ImageUrl` property, but this will be translated to something like `"www.mywebsite.com/C:\wwwroot\somefile.gif"`

Comment: sorry for jumping like this with runat="server" :) I misread your question

Answer (score 0):

Try not to set the `Server.MapPath` - just use:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/SME IMAGE/anonymous_avatar.gif";
```

Maybe make sure the url exists, and maybe add `%20` instead of the space in the path. (Also try to avoid spaces in paths)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i am just curious that y it cannot use Server.MapPath =(

Comment: Because the Server.MapPath returns the physical file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) returns the **physical** file path that corresponds to the specified virtual path on the Web server. So when you setting

```
string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/SME IMAGE/anonymous_avatar.gif");
```

it could return something like `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\website\SME IMAGE\anonymous_avatar.gif` which is actually a physical path to the file.

[`Image.ImageUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx) property accepts the URL of an image to display in the `Image` control. You can use a relative or an absolute URL. MSDN says:

> A relative URL relates the location of the image to the location of
>   the Web page without specifying a complete path on the server. The
>   path is relative to the location of the Web page. This makes it easier
>   to move the entire site to another directory on the server without
>   updating the code. An absolute URL provides the complete path, so
>   moving the site to another directory requires that you update the
>   code.